# Workflow Lookup

Tags: workflow, workflow-lookup

I have a custom list which contains the following columns
1. Name
2. Team
3. Active Directory Account (This is a person/group lookup)
I am now creating another list which will contain a workflow that will need to check if the user currently working on the item belongs to a specific team based on the other list.
Example:
1. Name = Mr. Smith
2. Team = Finance
3. Active Directory Account = Mr.Smith in the person/group lookup
In my second list I will have a column for Finance, HR and a few others and what I need is a workflow which will update the relevant comment with the email address of the user e.g. Mr smith would update the finance column and if Mr.Bloggs from HR edits the item the HR column will be updated with his email. I just can't seem to put the logic together to get htis to work does anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

You can either create a new column for this purpose or change the existing `Modified By` column.

If you choose the latter and set it to 'work email', it will display the user's email address instead.

Does this achieve what you are looking to do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: So let's say list 1 is "Team Info" and list 2 is "Reports". When Mr smith modifies an item in reports I want the workflow to check against the team info list and if his team equals finance then the finance column in reports will update with his email address. Then say Mr. Bloggs modifies the same item but his team equals HR in the team info list then this will update the HR column in the reports list with his email address.  I just can't seem to figure out the logic for the workflow

Comment: I have just managed to come up with a working solution. I  went off for a few minutes came back and I guess the penny dropped. I set a workflow variable that looks up the team of the current item:Modified By within the team info list and then set If variable equals finance update Current Item:Finance with Current Item:Modified By. I set the return field as email. This works exactly how I needed it to but thank you for your answer.